# Lucas sequence implementation

Tags: python, primes, mathematics, fibonacci-sequence

Could you suggest any improvements in this [Lucas sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasSequence.html)'s implementation:

```
from mpmath.libmp import bitcount as _bitlength

def _int_tuple(*i):
    return tuple(int(_) for _ in i)

def _lucas_sequence(n, P, Q, k): 
    """Return the modular Lucas sequence (U_k, V_k, Q_k).
    Given a Lucas sequence defined by P, Q, returns the kth values for
    U and V, along with Q^k, all modulo n.
    """
    D = P*P - 4*Q
    if n < 2:
        raise ValueError("n must be >= 2")
    if k < 0:
        raise ValueError("k must be >= 0")
    if D == 0:
        raise ValueError("D must not be zero")

    if k == 0:
        return _int_tuple(0, 2, Q)
    U = 1
    V = P
    Qk = Q
    b = _bitlength(k)
    if Q == 1:
        # For strong tests
        while b > 1:
            U = (U*V) % n
            V = (V*V - 2) % n
            b -= 1
            if (k >> (b - 1)) & 1:
                t = U*D
                U = U*P + V
                if U & 1:
                    U += n
                U >>= 1
                V = V*P + t
                if V & 1:
                    V += n
                V >>= 1
    elif P == 1 and Q == -1:
        # For Selfridge parameters
        while b > 1:
            U = (U*V) % n
            if Qk == 1:
                V = (V*V - 2) % n
            else:
                V = (V*V + 2) % n
                Qk = 1
            b -= 1
            if (k >> (b-1)) & 1:
                t = U*D
                U = U + V
                if U & 1:
                    U += n
                U >>= 1
                V = V + t
                if V & 1:
                    V += n
                V >>= 1
                Qk = -1
    else:
        # The general case with any P and Q
        while b > 1:
            U = (U*V) % n
            V = (V*V - 2*Qk) % n
            Qk *= Qk
            b -= 1
            if (k >> (b - 1)) & 1:
                t = U*D
                U = U*P + V
                if U & 1:
                    U += n
                U >>= 1
                V = V*P + t
                if V & 1:
                    V += n
                V >>= 1
                Qk *= Q
            Qk %= n
    U %= n
    V %= n
    return _int_tuple(U, V, Qk)
```

Comment: The indentation of the last line is plain wrong. Can you check that this is the only one? Also, can you add the formal definition of this sequence?

Comment: Yes, my bad. And, you can read more about Lucas Sequence here : [Lucas Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasSequence.html)

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, so forgive my ignorance, but where is the `else` to the `if (k >> (b - 1)) & 1:` statement? If the next bit is `0`, there is still an operation you need to perform. Can you confirm that the code outputs correct results in its current state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     if D == 0:
>         raise ValueError("D must not be zero")
> ```

`D` is not a parameter, so it seems a bit strange to me to use its name in the exception error message.

Also, given that the reference you give defines Lucas sequences only for `D > 0`, it seems a bit strange that you're happy to have `D < 0`. It might be worth adding a comment to say that you're supporting negative determinants.

---

> ```
>         # For strong tests
> ```

I deduce from this that you're using the sequences for a Lucas or Lucas-Lehmer primality test, but that comment seems a bit out of place.

Having three cases also seems a bit overkill. Have you profiled the code to see how much of a difference the special cases make? You seem to mainly save a few multiplications by `1`, and I'm not convinced that the maintenance effort is a worthwhile tradeoff if it's only a 2% speedup in a function which probably won't be the bottleneck anyway.

---

> ```
> b = _bitlength(k)
> ...
>         while b > 1:
>             ...
>             b -= 1
>             if (k >> (b - 1)) & 1:
>                 ...
> ```

I had to test this code to be convinced that you hadn't got the bit-shifting backwards (i.e. that you really did want to work from the most-significant bit down to the least-significant). It does seem correct, but it's definitely too clever to go without a comment explaining *why* it's correct.

---

> ```
>                 t = U*D
>                 U = U*P + V
>                 if U & 1:
>                     U += n
>                 U >>= 1
>                 V = V*P + t
>                 if V & 1:
>                     V += n
>                 V >>= 1
> ```

One of the great features of Python which I wish more languages had is parallel assignment. I would ditch the temporary variable and expose the parallels between `U` and `V` as

```
                U, V = U*P + V, V*P + U*D
                if U & 1:
                    U += n
                if V & 1:
                    V += n
                U, V = U >> 1, V >> 1
```

---

> ```
>     U %= n
>     V %= n
>     return _int_tuple(U, V, Qk)
> ```

In my opinion it's not putting too much into a line to make that (following Graipher's suggestion)

```
    return (U % n, V % n, Qk)
```

Comment: I can't answer for the OP code, but in a C implementation, the P=1,Q=-1 case comes out about 30% faster than the generic case, and is hit by about 50% of inputs to Lucas/Strong Lucas test.  Generic: 3 mulmod + 4/odd bit.  P=1,Q=-1:  2 mulmod + 1/odd bit.  Q=1:  2 mulmod + 3/odd bit.  (OP's code matches this also).  The Q=1 case is used for the extra strong Lucas test.

Answer (score 2):

Your `_int_tuple` function does not seem to serve any real purpose. `U` and `V` are always integers (you initialize them to `1` and do only arithmetic on them afterwards). And what exactly your program will do with a `Q` which is e.g. a string is hard to follow, but I think it will run into the `else` block (`Q` is neither `1` nor `-1`) and then try to do `Qk = Q`, followed by `Qk *= Qk` which fails for almost everything but number types.

I also can't see any parts of your code which would produce a `float` (though I might have overlooked one).

So I would get rid of that function and return just a tuple and see what it does.

Answer (score 2):

In general it looks good to me.  I'd clarify the comments a bit more.  Q=1 is typically used for the extra strong Lucas test, P=1,Q=-1 is used by about half the cases for the standard or strong Lucas test (the rest have a different Q).  Some info on the various tests can be seen on my [Pseudoprime Statistics](http://ntheory.org/pseudoprimes.html) page.

What happens if n is even?  For example, Lucas_5(6,1) = (1189,6726).  Mod 1000 should yield (189,726).  But the routine gives us (689,726).  This is an artifact of the halving method used.  My solution was to use a different, slower, method in that case, since it's rarely used (never by a standard primality test, but there are more uses that just those).

For D=0, we can return a solution.  See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence#Repeated_root).

Check the cases where P and/or Q and/or D exceeds n.  It looks from a quick test that the returned Q_k values are out of range for k={0,1}.  Doing a check and mod up front may improve performance.

Consider `k.bit_length()` instead of using libmp.  Up to you, but I like fewer dependencies.  I don't know all the tradeoffs between the two however.

For the Q=1 case (used by the extra strong Lucas test) there is yet another method that can be faster.  If D can be inverted mod n, then we can calculate V_k with 2 mulmods per bit, then compute U_k using the inverse.  I hate to add more cases, and of course you'd need to benchmark to see if it worked better for your infrastructure and use.